# Rails 4 better way to change :url/:id params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to figure this out for hours but couldn't find an answer fo that in rails 4! What is the better way to change the :id params to something else? I am trying to do

```
resources :articles, param: :article_title
```

But it is not working! I receive a message "Couldn 't find an article without an ID"...
Thanks!

Comment: what does your code that does the lookup, look like? What URL are you visiting? There's simply not enough information here to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to make your URLs look more like "/articles/my-article-title" instead of "/articles/456"? There are a [number of ways](https://gist.github.com/agnellvj/1209733) to do this, but the cleanest way would be to use the [friendly_id gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id).

Answer (score 0):

**Routes**

You're trying to create [`semantic URLs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL)

These basically allow you to include [`slugs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL#Slug) in your application, as opposed to the standard `id` setup which Rails uses by default:

[image]

--

**Slugs**

The trick to get this set up is to set up your ActiveRecord `.find` method to look up more columns than the standard `id` (which is the default)

As mentioned by `Alex P`, you'll want to use a gem called [`friendly_id`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) to this. There's a great `RailsCast` on this topic:

[image]

The trick here is to acknowledge the fact that the `routes` you use will still pass the `params[:id]` value to your application; it's how you manage the use / processing of this value which counts

Typically, you'll use the `.find` ActiveRecord method to look up the `id` for the `params[:id]` value. `friendly_id` actually changes this to search the `slug` column too - allowing you to use `.find` to look up slugs:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :articles #-> domain.com/articles/:id

#app/models/article.rb
Class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   extend FriendlyID
   friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]
end

#app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
Class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @article = Article.find params[:id] -> will look up the slug ;)
   end
end
```